# OS Reboot, Shutdown, Hibernate, Sleep, Wakeup (Windows Python)

Tags: python, windows, power-management

I'm looking for an automatize way of doing Windows Power Management functions:
- Reboot
- Shutdown
- Hibernate
- Sleep
- Wakeup

Is there a Python module to cover this functionality?
Of course any other solutions are also appreciated...

Answer (score 3):

I also went with the command line:

```
import os
os.system(r'%windir%\system32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState Hibernate')
```

Answer (score 2):

See [`win32api.ExitWindowsEx()`](http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.5/pywin32/win32api__ExitWindowsEx_meth.html) ActiveState documentation.

for flags: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

for hybernate/sleep: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373201%28v=vs.85%29.aspx 
to use this one you need to use`ctypes`since looks like `pywin32` does not implement it.

Wakeup? I doubt you can execute code while sleeping. :)

Comment: For wakeup remember there is WakeUpOnLAN, so from another device (phone, tablet) it should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to comment on an answer (yet). But I came here looking for an alternative *because* I was trying to avoid using the command line, so I just have to say this: I don't think calling SetSuspendState directly is the answer.

Take a look here for a reason: 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/15/58973.aspx
(short version: bad things may happen. Long version: unexpected function signature corrupts the stack).

If you need another reason, it seems to simply... not work in Win7 (no matter what you pass as parameters, it always goes to hibernate - never to standby). At least that's what happened to me, and from what I read online I'm not the only one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `shutdown` command for that.

Example:

```py
import os
os.system("shutdown -s -t 0")
```

This will shutdown the computer (-s) with a delay of 0 seconds (-t 0) for an instant shutdown. For the full usage, go here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/shutdown